# How to write a code which detects 3 consecutive candles in 2 scenarios

Tags: charts, candlestick-chart

I need help in identifying 3 consecutive candles in 2 different cases.

Case 1

The left and right candles have equal wicks that are greater than the wick of the middle candle.

Case 2

The left and right candles have equal wicks that are lesser than the wicks of the middle candle.

This should be identifiable mainly in M1 to M15 time frames.

I didn't try anything because I don't know how to code, hence I'm asking for help.